# How to deal with libraries requiring unique_ptr as inputs in pybind11?

Tags: c++, polymorphism, unique-ptr, pybind11

C++ libraries that involve dynamic runtime polymorphism may choose to use `std::unique_ptr` to pass instances around. Given a basic type hierarchy like:

```cpp
struct Animal
{
  virtual ~Animal() = default;
  virtual std::string makeSound() const = 0;
};

struct Dog : public Animal
{
  std::string makeSound() const
  {
    return "woof";
  }
};

struct Cat : public Animal
{
  std::string makeSound() const
  {
    return "meow";
  }
};
```

This library may offer functions like these:

```cpp
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Animal>> createAnimals()
{
  std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Animal>> animals;
  animals.emplace_back(std::make_unique<Dog>());
  animals.emplace_back(std::make_unique<Cat>());
  return animals;
}

void doSomethingWithAnimals(const std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Animal>>& animals)
{
  for (const auto& animal : animals) {
    animal->makeSound();
  }
}
```

I'm wondering how to write pybind11 bindings for these functions? The obvious approach is:

```cpp
PYBIND11_MODULE(my_native_module, m)
{
  py::class_<Animal>(m, "Animal");

  m.def("create_animals", &createAnimals);
  m.def("do_something_with_animals", &doSomethingWithAnimals);
}
```

The binding of `createAnimals` works fine, and in fact closely follows the pybind11 documentation example on [inheritance (see `PolymorphicPet`)](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/classes.html#inheritance).

On the other hand, the binding `doSomethingWithAnimals` doesn't compile, and actually runs into a rather fundamental limitation, which is documented in the [smart pointers section](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/smart_ptrs.html#std-unique-ptr):

> While returning unique pointers in this way is allowed, it is illegal to use them as function arguments.
> [...]
> The above signature would imply that Python needs to give up ownership of an object that is passed to this function, which is generally not possible.

This somehow makes sense, but there seems to be little value of being able to return an `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>>` in a binding, if this instance cannot be passed back in anywhere.

The section on smart pointers continues to explain that raw pointers and shared pointers are a possible solution. But what if this library is a third party library, or simply cannot be refactored in its entirety to use e.g. raw pointers? Is there no way at all to write pybind11 bindings in such a case?

---

I guess something dirty like the following doesn't do the job: It now compiles, but it will segfault at runtime, presumably because now the destruction of the unique pointer deletes the instances, but Python still holds references to them...

```cpp
  // Dirty hack, trying to wrap the `doSomethingWithAnimals` call behind a raw pointer interface:
  m.def("do_something_with_animals_dangerous", [](const std::vector<Animal*>& animals) {
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Animal>> animals_unique_ptrs;
    for (const auto raw_ptr : animals) {
      animals_unique_ptrs.push_back(std::unique_ptr<Animal>(raw_ptr));
    }
    doSomethingWithAnimals(animals_unique_ptrs);
  });
```

Comment: C++ is such a bad pile of available paradigms often exposed in external interfaces. We commonly have to wrap such part of interface into something more constrained for to communicate with other language. Move semantics (of unique_ptr) can be perhaps interfaced to Rust, Swift, and D. I don't think that Python gets it.

Comment: Admittedly such an interface violates [isocpp core guideline F.7](http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#f7-for-general-use-take-t-or-t-arguments-rather-than-smart-pointers), but it is still understandable why a library author may prefer to use vectors of unique pointers instead of vectors of raw pointers in their interfaces if doing so consistently...

Comment: Wrap a `unique_ptr<Animal>` in a class, say `AnimalHandle`. Add forwarding methods, and export that to Python instead of `Animal`. Now you can manipulate `unique_prt`s in Python. Not the same way as raw pointers, but still.